# What are the macrostates and microstates of a system submerged in a heat bath?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Let $A$ be the set of macrostates of a system. For each macrostate $a \in A$, there is a set of corresponding microstates $\{ a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n \}$. The principle of equal a priori probabilities states that the probability for any microstate $a_i$ corresponding to a particular equilibrium macrostate $a$ is equal.

On page 54 In F. Mandl's statistical mechanics 1st edition, it states that the macrostate of a system in equilibrium with a heat bath is specified by $(T,V,N)$, the temperature, volume and particle number. He then states there will be multiple microstates which have probabilities

$$ p(a_i) = \frac{1}{Z} e^{- \beta E_i}$$

where $E_i$ is the energy of the microstate $a_i$. If a system in a heat bath has a constant temperature $T$, volume $V$ and particle number $N$, then there exists only one possible macrostate $(T,V,N)$ because we assume our system is in equilibrium with the heat bath.

**Questions**

1. If there exists only one possible macrostate of the system, namely $(T,V,N)$, then surely all microstate probabilities should be equal due to equal a priori probabilities and not given by the Gibbs distribution?
2. How is it possible that a system with fixed $V$ and $N$ can have different energies but
   remain at the same temperature?
3. In the canonical ensemble, is the energy of the system considered a microstate or a macrostate?

Comment: Q2 sounds to me something like "How is it possible that the value of $Q$ can have different values for the same  mean value $Q_{mean}$ ?"